# Semanticui sticky menu with visible sidebar

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui, sticky

I cannot make work a semanticui sticky menu when I set a `visible` sidebar. There is [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azmeuk/bdpz9wch/10/) explaining the issue. The top menu glitches and does not seem to follow the scroll.

```
<div class="example">

  <div class="ui visible inverted left vertical sidebar menu" id="left-menu">
    <a class="item">Option 1</a>
  </div>

  <div class="pusher">

    <div class="ui sticky menu" id="top-menu">
      <a class="item">Menu</a>
    </div>

    <div style="height:3000px; background-color:red;">
      Example with ui sticky menu
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<script>$(function(){ $('#top-menu').sticky(); });</script>
```

Do you know how to fix this?